# Finding a function from a fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Taken from Apostol Analysis, it says, find a continuous function that generates the fourier series:

$$ \sum_{n} \frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n^3} \sin(nx) $$

I really have no idea how to solve this, instinctively I tried solving $\langle f,\sin(nx)\rangle =  \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}$ and $\langle f,\cos(nx)\rangle =  0$ and got nowhere, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would start by calculating the Fourier series of $ax^3 + bx$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ with $2\pi$ periodic boundary conditions.  But that is a guess based upon prior experience.

Comment: Differentiating the series formally (that is, without proper justification), we get 
$$f''(x) =- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin (nx)$$
which is a series you might recognize (it's a piecewise linear function, and you may have  a similar example in the book). If you can identify this function, then $f$ can be found by integration. The lack of justification is not an issue then, because you can check directly that $f$ has the right Fourier coefficients.

Comment: thank you both for your answers, they really helped. If anyone is interested the solution is indeed a cubic polynomial of the form $\frac{ x^3 - x{\pi}^2}{12}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observations:

1. $f$ is odd
2. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, because the series converges uniformly. Together with 1, this implies $f(\pi)=0$.
3. $f$ is a cubic polynomial on $(-\pi,\pi)$, because the Fourier coefficients of $x^k$ involve $1/n^k$ (integration by parts happens $k$ times).

Odd cubic polynomials vanishing at $\pi$ are of the form $A(x^3-\pi^2 x)$. There are various ways to find $A$, including boring integration. A less boring way is to   observe that
$$ f'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}\cos nx$$ 
is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and 
$$f'(\pi)=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$
Since $A(x^3-\pi^2 x)'=A(3x^2-\pi^2)$ evaluates to $2\pi^2A$ at $x=\pi$, we have $A=1/12$.

Comment: Great answer! As a newbie I have two further questions. Can you suggest a source for item 3 that I can read and understand? Also, you state *"odd cubic polynomials vanishing at $\pi$ are of the form...".* Is there such a list to refer to?

Comment: To find the Fourier coefficients of $x^kf(x)$ we can do $k$ integrations by parts ($u=f$, $v’=\cos/\sin$) to reduce it to the Fourier coefficients of $f$, but meanwhile, we gained a factor of $1/n^k$ (can be proved by induction on $k$). 
Take a general expression of a 3rd degree polynomial, check that the parity requirement throws out the even coefficients, then that the root at pi gives the expression above.