# Find a function if the fourier series is given

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I am wondering how to find a closed-form expression for the fourier coefficients $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, i.e. I am looking for a function $f$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ that generates the fourier series

$$f(x)=\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \cos(nx)$$

What I know from this [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608698/finding-a-function-from-a-fourier-series) is the fact that the function

- should be even
- should be linear because the Fourier coefficients of $x^k$ involve $\frac{1}{n^k}$.

But if $f$ is even and should be linear, it can only be a constant function. So I am not sure if it is not possible or I made a mistake.

The graph looks [like a half-circle](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot%5C%2840%29Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2Cn%5D*cos%5C%2840%29n*x%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%5C%2844%29x%5C%2844%29-pi%5C%2844%29pi%5C%2841%29) and diverges for $x = \pm \pi$ because $f(\pm \pi)=\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

A similar post is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645391/retrieving-function-from-fourier-coefficients-c-n-1-n).

Comment: Some ideas: $f$ is the real part of $$F(x)=\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{inx}=\sum\frac1ne^{i(x+\pi)n}.$$ So you only need to compute $\sum\frac1nz^n$, which can be viewed as the anti-derivative of a geometric series. Maybe some more work should be done to make things rigorous.

Comment: The function is not linear.  Examine the reasons you thought it is.

Comment: for me the graph looks more like $\frac{1}{sin^2(x/3-\pi/2)-c}$ not like a circle

Comment: Using @Feng's comment I've got something like $f(x)=\frac{1}{(\cos(x+\pi)-x)^2}$ which has a similar shape but is not correct.

Comment: This is $-\ln\big(2\cos\frac{x}{2}\big)$

Comment: I think you mean $f(\pm\pi) = \sum_n 1/n$ for the divergent sum.

Comment: The polynomial argument from the linked post is missing a condition. Namely, that odd $k$ are coefficients of $\sin(n x)$ and even $k$ are coefficients of $\cos(n x)$. Here you have odd $k$ on $\cos(n x)$ terms, so it doesn't work. If your function was instead $\sum_n (-1)^n/n \sin(n x)$, you would indeed get a linear function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completness:

We have
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \cos(nx)=\Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{i\pi n}e^{ixn}\right)=\Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{i(x+\pi)n}\right)=\Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}z^n\right)$$
with $z=e^{i(x+\pi)}$.

If we take the derivative, we get a geometric series
$$f'(x)=\Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

So we get $f$ by integrating
$$f(x)=\Re\left(-\ln(1-z)\right)+c.$$
Since $f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\ln(2)$ we can conclude that $c=0$. So we are left with
$$f(x)=-\Re\left(\ln(1-z)\right)=-\Re\left(\ln(1-e^{i(x+\pi)})\right)=-\Re\left(\ln(1+e^{ix})\right).$$
Using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260028/find-the-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-lnz) with $x=1+\cos(x)$ and $y=\sin(x)$ we can rewrite the $\ln$-expression:
$\ln(1+e^{ix})=\ln(\sqrt{2\cos(x)+2})+i\theta$
and we get the final result
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \ln\left(2(\cos(x)+1)\right)=-\ln(2\cos(\frac{x}{2})).$$